# HTML files not being overwritten in app/Design

Tags: javascript, overrides, html, magento2.4

I'm trying to override html files the same way that I would override a phtml file, but it doesn't seem to be working. Same with Javascript.

I'm trying to change some logic in minicart.js.

I put my file into `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js`
Original file in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js`

I cleared all of the caches and disabled my browser cache, but when I search for minicart.js in the network tab, it's still the original file.

Same issue with HTML files.

No issue at all with phtml files at all.

Based on the docs, this sounds like it should work seamlessly

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the files into wrong location, the location of vendor file is:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

And you are putting it into:

> app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

but it should be and this will work perfect

> app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/minicart.js

You can do the same with with the html files as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did it. Thank you. It's a little strange that copying the original path didn't work.

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai Pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328962/85907